# Multivariable calculus discontinuities question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, characteristic-functions, continuity

Question: If D is the set of discontinuities of $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, show that the set of discontinuities of $f_{\Phi_{A}}$ is contained in $D \bigcup \partial A$.

So, $f_{\Phi_{A}}$ is the characteristic function of $f$, which is  \begin{cases} 
      1 & if x\in A \\
      0 & if x\notin A \\
   \end{cases}
Then, pick a point $p\in f_{\Phi_{A}}$ and show that $p$ is contained in $D \bigcup \partial A$.
Is this the right way to prove this? Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to show is $f\Phi $ is continuous at $x$ if $x \notin D\cup \partial A$. So assume $x \notin D\cup \partial A$ and take $x_n \to x$. Since $x \notin  \partial A$, either $x$ is in the interior of $A$ or in the exterior. In the first case $x_n$ is also in the interior of $A$ (hence in $A$) for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $(f\Phi )(x_n)=f (x_n) \to f(x) =(f\Phi ) (x)$ because $x \notin D$. Similar argument in the second case.